# C++ stack overflow error, even though i use a pointer array

Tags: c++, heap-memory, overflow, quicksort, stack-memory

Hello im trying to test a algorithm(Quicksort) by sorting an array with 1 000 000 numbers but i get a stack overflow error. I found out earlier that i should save the array on the heap instead of the stack. So i did it like this.

```
    int *enMiljon = new int[1000000];
```

Instead of this:

```
    int enMiljon[1000000] = {};
```

This is how i call the function and how it looks like:

```
    quicksortPivotLast(enMiljon, 999999);
```

```
template <typename T>
int partitionPivotLast(T arr[], int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int pivot = arr[endIndex]; // Constant time= C1
    int count = 0; // Constant time= C2
    

    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) { // Linear time= n
        if (arr[i] <= pivot) // Constant time= C3
        {
            count++; // Constant time= C4
        }
    }

    int indexP = startIndex + count; // Constant time= C5
    swap(arr[indexP], arr[endIndex]); // Constant time= C6

    int i = startIndex; // Constant time= C7
    int j = endIndex; // Constant time= C8

    while (i < indexP && j > indexP) { // linear time=n

        while (arr[i] <= pivot) { // Linear time = n/2 or n
            i++;
        }
        while (arr[j] > pivot) { // Linear time = n/2 or n
            j--;
        }
        if (i < indexP && j > indexP) { // Constant time= C9
            swap(arr[i++], arr[j--]); // Constant time= C10
        }
    }
    return indexP;
    //T(n)=O(4c+2c+2c*n+2c*3n+logn)
}

template<typename T>
void quicksortPivotLastTwo(T arr[], int startIndex, int endIndex) {

    if (startIndex >= endIndex) // Constant time= C1
    {
        return;
    }

    // partitioning the array
    int p = partitionPivotLast(arr, startIndex, endIndex); // Constant time= C2

    // Sorting the left part
    quicksortPivotLastTwo(arr, startIndex, p - 1); // Constant time= C3

    // Sorting the right part
    quicksortPivotLastTwo(arr, p + 1, endIndex); // Constant time= C4

}

template<typename T>
void quicksortPivotLast(T arr[], int n)
{
    quicksortPivotLastTwo(arr, 0, n);
}
```

But i still get stack overflow error. Does anyone know how i should do?

Comment: Probably you have **infinite recursion**. It doesn't matter how small your use of the stack is, if you continue growing the stack for ever it will overflow. Unfortunately since you have only posted a couple of lines of code it's hard to say any more.

Comment: The two initializations you are showing are not equivalent. The `new` expression doesn't end with `{}` and therefore will not initialize the array elements, while the second line with `= {}` will initialize all elements to zero.

Comment: No, it works tottaly fine on smaller arrays. This is the first array i get stack overflow on, and ive tried from 1000 numbers up to 100 000.

Comment: @TylerDurden Well then maybe we need to see the code, so we can suggest improvements. Do you know how big your stack is BTW?

Comment: @TylerDurden It doesn't have to be actual infinite recursion. Deep but finite recursion can also be a problem. Also, you could have a bug that causes infinite recursion only when the array is large. Also, how did you determine that the issue is a stack overflow and not something else? Except if you are using a sanitizer (which would also give you detailed information like a stack trace), you usually only get a segmentation fault which can have all kinds of causes.

Comment: Ok, but i just want to create space for the numbers with that line and then get the numbers from text file. Does that mather?

Comment: Ok, i uploaded the code now

Comment: Run the program in a debugger. It will show you the stack trace at the point of the segmentation fault or stack overflow. Have a look whether it shows deeply nested calls to `quicksortPivotLastTwo`. The problem with a recursive algorithm as you are showing is that a bad choice of pivot can easily cause the recursion to become too deeply nested.

Comment: Using the last element as the pivot will certainly cause worst case performance and recursion levels with sorted out near sorted inputs. However coded correctly there should still only be 20 levels of recursion which shouldn't cause a stack overflow. Definitely time to break out the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurse on smaller partition, loop on larger partition. This will limit stack space complexity to O(log2(n)), but worst case time complexity remains at O(n^2).

```
template<typename T>
void quicksortPivotLastTwo(T arr[], int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    while(startIndex < endIndex)
    {
        int p = partitionPivotLast(arr, startIndex, endIndex);
        if((p - startIndex) <= (endIndex - p)){
            quicksortPivotLastTwo(arr, startIndex, p - 1);
            startIndex = p+1;
        } else {
            quicksortPivotLastTwo(arr, p + 1, endIndex);
            endIndex = p-1;
        }
    }
```